# Open Excel File with Task Manager, Run Macro, Save file, and close

Tags: excel, macros, taskmanager, vba

I am trying to get an excel file to open up every morning at 5am, run a macro which pulls in data and filers/organizes the data, save the file and then close it. I currently have the task manager with the .vbs script to open the file which is below, and the file opens, but as it closes the Save window pops up, and tries to save the file as a copy of the original.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

 ' Import Add-Ins
'xlApp.Workbooks.Open "G:\CNC\Schiermeyer\Active Job Files\Autorefresh" "C:\<pathOfXlaFile>\MyMacro.xla"
'xlApp.AddIns("MyMacro").Installed = True

'Open Excel workbook
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\CNC\Schiermeyer\Active Job Files\Autorefresh\AutoRefresh Active Job Report.xlsm", 0, True)

' Run Macro
xlApp.Run "sheet1.ActiveJobReportRefresh"

xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to using Task manager & .vbs files, and still not a pro with VBA, this is just as far as I have gotten using forums.

Comment: To execute the vbs script use Windows Task Scheduler to execute the vbs file daily at 5am.

Comment: `xlBook.Close False` will tell Excel to not save any changes

Comment: I also ran into the issue of the task manager saying that the task has started but it would just continue running.,

Comment: Mitch, I was able to do that, the issue was more that the file wouldn't save, or close.

Comment: Tim, I need the file to save before closing

Comment: You need the vbs file or the excel file to save first?  I assume the Excel file.  Try something to the effect of this in your VBA in your workbook: ThisWorkbook.Save before your workbook.close command.

Comment: I added a save command to the VBA, so if I run the macro inside the excel file it will save and I can close it.  When I try to do it through the task manager, the file opens, runs the macro, and then I get the pop up that says" A file name 'AutoRefresh Active Job Report.xlsm' already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?" 

This is where I am stuck. Not sure if it is something with my VBA in the macro, or the VBS script.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your excel VBA

Answer (score 1):

I created a module and inserted the below code:

```
Sub Auto_Close()

If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End If

End Sub
```

But this module is created where when the user click the close (X) on top right, excel will save and close by not asking confirmation. Perhaps you can try to modify this code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save to the same workbook, you need to open the workbook as "write-able". i.e.:

`Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\CNC\Schiermeyer\Active Job Files\Autorefresh\AutoRefresh Active Job Report.xlsm", 0, False)`